# I needed help --> How can I get multiple row to one row with user defined columns?

Tags: sql

How can I get multiple rows to one row with user-defined columns? (Pivot)

-- Input Table

```
----------------------------------------------- <br/>
UniqID | ServiceID | ServiceFrom | ServiceTo  | <br/>
----------------------------------------------- <br/>
1234   | 1234      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
1234   | 1324      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
1234   | 1342      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
1234   | 1213      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
1234   | 1243      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
1234   | 1215      | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 | <br/>
----------------------------------------------- <br/>
```

-- Output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/>
UniqID | ServiceFrom | ServiceTo  | PR1 | PR2 | PR3 | PR4 | PR5 | PR6 | <br/>
----------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/>
1234   | 2023-01-10  | 2023-01-10 |1234 | 1324| 1342| 1213| 1243| 1215| <br/>
----------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/>
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

-Aquaroyal72

Comment: is the number of PR columns, fixed? like in this case it looks like PR1 to PR6. so is it expected to have 6 entries for each UniqID?

Comment: @Anand Vidvat -ServiceID may be more than 6, but it only uses 1st 6 unique values. ServiceID column is split into PR1 to PR6 custom columns. Thank you for your help.

Comment: one way to look at this problem is to use a rank() window function which would rank each entry for a specific uniqueID and ServiceFrom and ServiceTo combination then you can use filter conditions to create 6 different tables and apply an inner join to extract those 6 columns.

Comment: - Any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data (added a few more rows):

```
SQL> select * from test;

    UNIQID  SERVICEID SERVICEFRO SERVICETO
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1234       1234 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      1234       1324 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      1234       1342 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      1234       1213 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      1234       1243 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      1234       1215 2023-01-10 2023-01-10
      5555       2234 2023-02-15 2023-02-17
      5555       5242 2023-03-18 2023-04-19

8 rows selected.
```

The following query uses a CTE to prepare data by "sorting" them per each `uniqid` by `serviceid` (you could use a subquery instead; result would be the same). The final query uses conditional aggregation to fetch the first 6 `PR` values; dates are set to minimum start and maximum end date per each `uniqid`.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select uniqid, serviceid, servicefrom, serviceto,
  3       row_number() Over (partition by uniqid order by serviceid) rn
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select uniqid,
  7         min(servicefrom) servicefrom,
  8         max(serviceto)   serviceto,
  9         min(case when rn = 1 then serviceid end) pr1,
 10         min(case when rn = 2 then serviceid end) pr2,
 11         min(case when rn = 3 then serviceid end) pr3,
 12         min(case when rn = 4 then serviceid end) pr4,
 13         min(case when rn = 5 then serviceid end) pr5,
 14         min(case when rn = 6 then serviceid end) pr6
 15  from temp
 16  group by uniqid;

    UNIQID SERVICEFRO SERVICETO         PR1        PR2        PR3        PR4        PR5        PR6
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1234 2023-01-10 2023-01-10       1213       1215       1234       1243       1324       1342
      5555 2023-02-15 2023-04-19       2234       5242

SQL>
```